# Homomorphisms and Complex Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the function $f : \mathbb C^*\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ defined by $f(a+bi) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is a homomorphism, and describe its kernel.

I'm running into a little trouble proving a homomorphism. How I do the $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ parts like this? Do I need a $c$ and a $d$ to make an $f(c+di)$? When I plug in $f(a)$, it looks almost like it should be $\sqrt{a^2}$, but that can't be right.

I don't have a clue on the kernel front. Thanks for any help!

(Sorry the formatting didn't turn out, it looked like I did it right...)

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is confusing you: the $a$ and $b$ in $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ are not the real and imaginary parts of a complex number, as they are in $a+bi$.

What you need to show is that if $z_1, z_2\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f(z_1z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$. To do this, say $z_1:=a+bi$ and $z_2:=c+di$.

Then $z_1z_2=(a+bi)(c+di)=ac-db+(ad+bc)i$.

So $$f(z_1z_2)=\sqrt{(ac-db)^2+(ad+bc)^2}=\sqrt{a^2c^2-2abcd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+2abcd+b^2c^2}$$
But $f(z_1)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $f(z_2)=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$, so $$f(z_1)f(z_2)=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}=\sqrt{a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2}$$

EDIT: As for the kernel, you need to think about the preimage of the identity element in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. In other words, you must describe the complex numbers in $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ that get mapped to the identity in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

So first you need to get clear about what the identity element even is. I'm assuming you're thinking of a **group** homomorphism, interpreting $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ as the group of complex numbers under multiplication and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ as the group of positive reals under multiplication. What is the identity element in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$? It's the real number $1$. So you need to think about which complex numbers get mapped to 1 under this function $f$.

Hint: interpret a complex number $z=a+bi$ as a two-dimensional vector. What does $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ measure? What complex numbers would have $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints....

To show that $f$ is a homomorphism, take two arbitrary complex numbers from $\mathbb{C}^*$.  Then, show that

$$f(a)f(b) = f(ab)$$

where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.  Be sure to set $a = a_1 + a_2i$ and $b = b_1 + b_2i$ since you are working with complex numbers.  Then, evaluate $f$ at those values, including their product.

Also, for the kernel, determine what element in $\mathbb{C}^*$ is mapped into the ring of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$